# Twitter API with iron-ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter, iron-ajax

I have an `iron-ajax` element set up:

```
<iron-ajax
  id="get-tweets"
  url="http://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=nasa&result_type=popular"
  handle-as="json"
  on-response="handleResponse"
  debounce-duration="300">
</iron-ajax>
```

And I'm trying to pass an authentication header to it for Twitter, but I can't figure out how. Twitter has an [example request](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html) and I'm trying to figure out how to pass the header to the ajax request:

```
getTweets() {
  const ajax = this.root.querySelector('#get-tweets');
  ajax.headers = Object.assign(ajax.headers, `what do I put here?`
  });
  ajax.generateRequest();
},
```

I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Let's say I have the following:

```
Consumer API keys:
abc (API key)
def (API secret key)
Access token & access token secret:
gh-ijk (Access token)
lmn (Access token secret)
Read and write (Access level)
```

How do I pass this info to the `iron-ajax` element so I can make the request?

Comment: Secret keys never belong in client side code. You need server side proxy to protect them and to make the requests to the api

Comment: Yeah I'll do that if I publish the code but I just need it to work real quick. Doesn't change the fact that I need to know the correct format on how to pass it.

Comment: But API's that have secret keys aren't CORS enabled usually to prevent people from exposing their credentials

Comment: Ok you know I'd be fine with any solution on how to ping Twitter with iron-ajax.

Comment: Create a server side proxy you call with iron-ajax and server requests the twitter data and returns it to your ajax request

Comment: Can you show me an example? I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Do a web search for ajax proxy and include any scripting language your server runs in the search term. Or use the appropriate SDK library https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/developer-utilities/twitter-libraries.html